# Can this function be made faster? Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a function that gets an array of DOM elements (based on tags) within a div.

```
Pseudocode:
1. Say I wanted to get all input and textarea elements within a table myTbl
2. Declare resultingArray = null
3. For each tag (ex: input, textarea)
4.   tagArray = Get all elements based on tag
5.   Create another array by manually looping through tagArray and adding 
it to resultingArray (the return type is dynamic collection and not an array.
```

Functionally, it works but it takes too long. Is there a way to do what I am trying to do faster?

Comment: You can use concat if you slice the collection first.  This is a very fast way to convert a dynamic node list into an array.  I've posted some code below, and there is good information here: http://shifteleven.com/articles/2007/06/28/array-like-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Ben's [elements idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413192/can-this-function-be-made-faster-javascript/1413211#1413211), here's another shot with a non nested loop.

```
var tagNames = { 'SELECT' : true, 'INPUT' : true, 'TEXTAREA' : true }; //use an object for faster lookups
var rawElemsArray = document.getElementById("form-name").elements;
var elems = [];
for (var i = rawElemsArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (tagNames[rawElemsArray[i].tagName]) {
        elems.push(rawElemsArray[i]);
    }
}
```

EDIT: `form.elements` is defined in level 0 DOM, so I bet it is cross-browser. You can also use `childNodes` (which is cross-browser too) if that serves your purpose. The difference between them is that `childNodes` selects all nodes (div, p, span etc) and also empty text nodes (in non-IE browsers) while `elements` returns only the form controls.

Comment: Very elegant. This should be considerably faster than looping over `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: This is great, but it does only work for form elements, and specifically form elements that are all in the same form.  I know that has been mentioned in Ben's post, but it seems important enough to mention again.

Comment: Is this solution cross browser compatible?

Answer (score 2):

This definitely the type of problem that begs for a jQuery solution

```
var $elements = jQuery( '#id-of-table input, #id-of-table textarea' );
$elements.each( function( i, element )
{
   // whatever you need here
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

If your inputs and textareas are all within the same `<form>`, take a look at the [form.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements) DOM property.  That way your code could be simplified to:

```
var resultingArray = document.getElementById("form-name").elements;
```

**Edit:**

If your list of tag names is dynamic and you can't use a library, I don't think you'll be able to easily get away from the looping approach, but you can try to make it as light-weight as possible:

```
var result = [], nTags = tags.length, elements, nElements;

for (var i = 0; i < nTags; i++) {
    elements = table.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    nElements = elements.length;

    for (var j = 0; j < nElements; j++) {
        result.push(element);
    }
}
```

You could perhaps look into XPath expressions as well, but beware browser differences (for example, the code below won't work in IE, though there is an alternative for it).

```
var result = document.evaluate(tags.join("|"), table, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
```

Comment: I dont want to get all the elements. Only a selected few (input, span etc -  this list is dynamically constructed)

Comment: I tried your solution. It works functionally. But it's actually taking 30% more than my previous solution :(

Comment: Good heavens.  I can't imagine why; that should be about as straightforward as it gets! ;-)

Comment: `for...in` isn't the right construct for looping over an Array or NodeList in JS, you need the `for(i= 0; i<n; i++)` form. For an Array, the values of tag will be 0, 1, 2 and so on; for the NodeList you would get method names. The XPath, on the other hand, should work fast where available.

Comment: @bobince — Right you are! Clearly, I was conflating `for...in` with `foreach...in`, which isn't even cross-browser. I've corrected my example.

Answer (score 1):

You can call or apply Array.slice to an HTMLCollection to convert it to a string.  That allows you to use concat, which I think is the fastest possible solution:

```
function getElementsByTagNames(context, tags) {
    var res = [], 
        i = tags.length,
        slice = Array.prototype.slice;

    // Convert HTMLCollections to arrays and push onto the res array
    while(i--) res.push(slice.call(context.getElementsByTagName(tags[i])));

    // Use one concat call to merge all the arrays
    return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], res);
}

getElementsByTagNames(document.body, ['input', 'textarea']);
```

Keep in mind that this does not return the nodes in document order.  It will return all the `<input>`s grouped together and all of the `<textarea>`s grouped together.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to do, but this might point you in the right direction (note that it uses jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStuff(){
        resultArr = [];
        var inputs = $('#myTbl').find('input');
        var tareas = $('#myTbl').find('textarea'); 
        // do the looping bit which I don't completely understand
    }
</script>
```

Comment: well the problem is I can't combine two arrays without looping through the elements manually. Maybe this will help : http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=47683

Comment: I cannot use JQuery. I am looking for a Javascript solution

Answer (score -1):

i had similar situation with a table of 5 columns and up to 1200 rows (not all rows had all columns filled)

So all i did was put onclick handlers on onmouseover event for a table cell (putting onclick hanlders immediately on td would take too long too). And onclick handler would create textarea with text found in table cell.

Then i just got away with jQuery selectors!